# SharePoint Online Search - Result Query based on regex IP address

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search, query-rule

I am building a technical documentation wiki using SharePoint Online. I am trying to create a result query that recognizes the user has entered an IP address and promotes the 'server' pages as results but it doesn't seem to recognize regular expressions (regex).

This first screenshot shows the query rule is set up so that if the user enters the word "server" or "svr" and something (eg IP address) it will promote the server pages - works great

[image]

This second screenshot shows me trying to use Regex for it so that it recongnises an IP address and doesn't need the key words "svr" or "server" but this doesn't work recognise an IP address and doesn't promote. [image]

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft have confirmed that SharePoint Online doesn't support 'Query matches this regular expression' at present.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e0322d97-ad36-4564-bb5c-bb4d1b0711c7/sharepoint-online-search-result-query-based-on-regex-ip-address?forum=sharepointsearch